# Is the $m_n=y_n+\sum_{i}^{n} c_i x_i$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

> Consider a bounded sequence $\{x_n\}$ and a subspace $Y$ of $\mathcal{l}_{\infty}$ convergent sequences $\{y_n\}$. What is the $Y+span\{x_n\}$?

Is the any $m_n\in Y+span\{x_n\}$ then $m_n=y_n+\sum_{i}^{n} c_i x_i$? Or $m_n=y_n+c x_i$ for some constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is ambiguous, but it looks like you are considering a single sequence $x\in\ell^\infty$. In that case, the span is simply $\{\lambda x:\ \lambda\in\mathbb C\}$. So an element of your new subspace is of the form $m=y+\lambda x$, with $y$ convergent and $\lambda\in \mathbb C$. Thus $m_n=y_n+\lambda x_n$.